# How to use one activity with multiple possible values

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So I have one activity with a list of profile names which needs to link to another screen with an extended profile description.

So is it possible to use the `putExtra()` and `getExtra()` methods of an intent to pass a value that can be used to refer to the `android:text`(of a `TextView`) and the `android:src` (of an `ImageView`)? If it is possible to achieve this, how would the code go?

Comment: Post what have you done so far.

Comment: I just have a bunch of buttons, when clicked, each needs to open an activity with individualized content

Comment: Sir, why dont you start of by google or search on stackoverflow on how to pass stuff through activities

Comment: I wanted to know whether the strings.xml resource could be referenced via intents. I couldn't find anything for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually passing a descriptor is better. If some data has to passed, i send the id with intent. then obtain the corresponding data using the id from the intent, and then use the data whichever way i want.

Example: I assume that each profile item in your list has an unique id. pass this id when creating the intent to launch the expanded profile activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(activitycontext, ExpandedProfileActivity.class);
i.putExtra("uniqueid", uniqueIDofIndividualProfile);
startActivity(i);
```

In ExpandedProfileActivity onCreate():

```
Intent i = getIntent();
long uniqueId = i.getLongExtra("uniqueid", -1L);

if (uniqueId != -1L) {
    // obtain data from database using uniqueId;
}
```

Comment: @LightMikeE added a simple example. more error-checking will be required

Comment: what function does the -1L perform?

Comment: @LightMikeE -1L is the default value. the intent holds key-value pairs. if the key "uniqueid" is not present, then the default we pass (as the 2nd arg) is returned... -1L in this case. It is a fallback

Comment: Resource identifiers in Android are of type *integer* not *long*.

Comment: How do I check whether I've got a certain id, and then set the textview to a certain value? I can't use an if to check for the uniqueId variable, because it's a long/int and the id is given as "bob" in the xml file.

Comment: @abforce thanks for the trivia. i never said i was passing a resource identifier. thought that was clear from my answer.

Comment: @LightMikeE "bob" would translate to "R.string.bob" ==> an integer

Comment: would this work:

if (uniqueId == R.id.bob)
        {
            TextView main=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.maintext);
            main.setText(R.string.bobdetails);

        }

Comment: if i used: Intent i = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("uniqueid", R.id.bob);
        startActivity(i);

in the first activity

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

First Activity

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, secondActivity.class);
// Text of the edit text
intent.putExtra(KEY_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());
// Id of the image in res folder
intent.putExtra(KEY_IMAGE, R.drawable.myimage);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity (onCreate)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TEXT, null);
int imageId = intent.getIntExtra(KEY_IMAGE, 0);
// do stuff with 'text' and 'imageId'
```

Comment: can i use text and imageId as references to the string.xml file, or should I just use them as plain variables?

Comment: @LightMikeE For texts both ways is okay (id or text itself) but for image, in my opinion, using *id* is much better.